# Android pre`loading Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, load

I have a question regarding the loading of the first Activity in my App. Before loading it, app shows this screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r33n3u3xfmth345/Screenshot_2013-08-16-12-02-08.png , and what I would like, is to load directly my Activity.

I'll mention that I`m using SherlockActivity, and I already tried setting the Theme both in Manifest or programatically in onCreate() of my Activity, with same result (pre-load`s with that screen for 2-3 secs, then loads my Activity).
Any thoughts ?

Comment: Show splash screen for 2 or 3 second and then load your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the **splash screen Activity** and after that you have to start your **own activity** from that Splash screen Activity.

Here is the code for **splashActivity.**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
private int splashTime = 3000;
private Thread thread;
private ProgressBar mSpinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mSpinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Splash_ProgressBar);
    mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);
    thread = new Thread(runable);
    thread.start(); 
}
public Runnable runable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(splashTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,YourActivityName.class));
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
};
}
```

Here is code for **activity_spalsh.xml** file .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#48AD83"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="  your app name "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#A52A2A" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/Splash_ProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it does the trick.. but could it be another way not to show that screen without adding a splash screen to app?